# asynchronous communication between server and webbowser

Tags: ajax

The server is monitoring the events in client web browser...If any events occured in client web browser,the server should be notified about that event and server should respond to that event (like invoking another java class in the server itself)...please help me with the code

Comment: Yeaaah, we're going to need you to be a little more specific with what you need help with. Keyword here being HELP, not doing your work.

Answer (score 1):

Construct an `XMLHttpRequest` for a URL that invokes the corresponding method on the appropriate Java class.

Answer (score 1):

See [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) as a starter.